# Problem setting up wp-cli ( bash: php: command not found )

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-studio-code, wp-cli

So i'm trying to setup WP-CLI.
I'm working with visual studio code and i installed Git Bash as terminal.

Following WP-CLI installation guide i need to download a file:

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar
```

Works fine and the download seems completed

Second step is to check if it works:

```
php wp-cli.phar --info
```

Returns an error:

```
bash: php: command not found
```

Looks like Git Bash can't access the PHP Path from Wamp. That's the conclusion i get from this post [PHP Command, not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009623/php-command-not-found#answer-43009817)

I can't find a solution to fix this problem, if you guys got one i'd be happy to read it

Answer (score 0):

[Follow](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/installing/)

1. Set path in PATH environment variable (Recommended)
2. You can [do](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/use-bash-shell-windows-10) this as well.